# i have to click the button thrice for it to respond

Tags: discord.js

i tried making a button mechanism for my economy bot. but, i have to click the button thrice for the button to work. like what?? and when that 2 button clicks didn't work, as i expected, it catched errors in the console.

> code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "apply",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        try {
        let button = new Discord.ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
        new Discord.ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('proceed')
            .setLabel('Click to proceed.')
            .setStyle(Discord.ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        )
        
        let embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setAuthor({
            name: `Requested by ${message.author.username}`,
            iconURL: message.author.avatarURL()
        })
        .setTitle("Welcome to The Office's Application Form.")
        .setDescription("Here, you'll choose what company you're going to work on. There will be 5 companies to choose on.")
        .setColor(0x3483eb)
        
        await message.reply({embeds: [embed], components: [button]})
        
        client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
            try {
            var buttons = new Discord.ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
            new Discord.ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('one')
                .setLabel('1')
                .setStyle(Discord.ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        )
            .addComponents(
            new Discord.ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("two")
                .setLabel('2')
                .setStyle(Discord.ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            )
            
            .addComponents(
            new Discord.ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('three')
                .setLabel('3')
                .setStyle(Discord.ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            )
            
            .addComponents(
            new Discord.ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('four')
                .setLabel('4')
                .setStyle(Discord.ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            )
            
            .addComponents(
            new Discord.ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('five')
                .setLabel('5')
                .setStyle(Discord.ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            )
            
            
            var authorID = interaction.member.id
            if (authorID !== message.author.id) return await interaction.reply({content: "Sorry, this button is not for you.", ephemeral: true})
            
            var embed2 = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            
            .setTitle("The Office's Application Form - Page 1")
            .setDescription("Which company you want to choose?")
            .addFields({
                name: "The Internet Military",
                value: "They monitor the internet, saving innocent childs from pedophiles, trying to stop hacking, and keeps the internet safe from malicious file.\nWeekly salary: $1.000"
            }, {
                name: "Dark Web Monitor",
                value: "They monitor the dark web and share it to the public about how dangerous the dark web is. They tell what just happened in the dark web to the public.\nWeekly salary: $1.250"
            }, {
                name: "Anti-scam Call Center",
                value: "They troll, expose, and keeps people safe from scam calls. They also made a daily leaderboard on how many scam calls they got.\nWeekly salary: $1.350"
            }, {
                name: "Discord Sub-staff",
                value: "Even tho they doesn't have any power on moderating the Discord app, they give advice and *slowly and surely* threatens \"rude\" Discord users to stop doing their rude activity.\nWeekly salary: $1.200"
            }, {
                name: "Support Center",
                value: "They give people a support on digital product even tho they doesn't have connection on the official support.\nWeekly salary: $1.100"
            })
            .setColor(0x3483eb)
            
            await interaction.update({embeds: [embed2], components: [buttons]})
            
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`trycatch block just catched an error: ${error} respect for the good catching tho`)
            }
            
                
                client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaktion) => {
                    try {
                        if (interaktion.customId === 'one') {
                            var embedforone = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle("The Office's Application Form - Page 1.1")
                            .setDescription('Which position would you like?')
                            .addFields({
                                name: "Monitor the Internet",
                                value: "You will monitor the internet's activity and reporting any suspicious activity to the team"
                            }, {
                                name: "Saving innocent childs from pedophiles",
                                value: "You will harmlessly break through people's direct messages for catching pedophiles and reporting them to the team."
                            }, {
                                name: "Trying to stop hacking",
                                value: "You will attack hackers from their activities."
                            }, {
                                name: "Keeping the internet safe from malicious file",
                                value: "You will scan every downloadable files on the Internet and tells people if it's malicious and reporting it to the team."
                            }, {
                                name: "Activities reporter",
                                value: "You will report every report the team has sent you to the government."
                            })
                            
                            .setColor(0x3483eb)
                            
                            await interaktion.update({embeds: [embedforone], components: []})
                        } else if (interaktion.customId === 'two') {
                            var embedfortwo = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
                            
                            .setTitle("The Office's Application Form - Page 1.2")
                            .setDescription('Which position would you like?')
                            .addFields({
                                name: "Monitor the dark web",
                                value: "You will monitor the dark web and send the informations to the team."
                            }, {
                                name: "Publisher",
                                value: "You will publish how dangerous is the dark web."
                            })
                            
                            .setColor(0x3483eb)
                            
                            await interaktion.update({embeds: [embedfortwo], components: []})
                        } else if (interaktion.customId === 'three') {
                            var embedforthree = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
                            
                            .setTitle("The Office's Application Form - Page 1.3")
                            .setDescription('Which position would you like?')
                            .addFields({
                                name: "Troller",
                                value: "You will troll the scammers that's been around"
                            }, {
                                name: "Exposer",
                                value: "You will expose the scammers that's been around"
                            }, {
                                name: "Troller + Exposer",
                                value: "You will troll and expose the scammers that's been around"
                            })
                            
                            await interaktion.update({embeds: [embedforthree], components: []})
                        } else if (interaktion.customId === 'four') {
                            var embedforfour = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
                            
                            .setTitle("The Office's Application Form - Page 1.4")
                            .setDescription('Which position would you like?')
                            .addFields({
                                name: "Advicer",
                                value: "You will give advice to the \"rude\" Discord users."
                            })
                            .setColor(0x3438eb)
                            
                            await interaktion.update({embeds: [embedforfour], components: []})
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e)
            }
                })
        })
    } catch (er) {
        console.log(er)
    }
    }
}
```

i tried to put the code in catch for it to "retry", i tried to use the deferReply until i realised it's interaction.update... yeah.

in the future i need to *extend* my code and tried to make my first proper bot in djs. i'm a beginner, if i miss something pls tell me.

Comment: You shouldn't have event listeners inside other event listeners. Just in this code, you have two event listeners for `interactionCreate` inside (what I think is) an event listener for `messageCreate`.

Comment: so what should i do? where do i put my button's code? index.js?